# parsing pdf in perl

Tags: perl, parsing, pdf

I am trying to extract some information from pdf. I am trying to use  `getpdftext.pl` from the `CAM::PDF` module. When I just run `$~ getpdftext.pl sample.pdf`, it produces a text of the pdf to stdout.

But I am thinking of writing this to a textfile and parse for required fields in perl. Can someone please guide me on how to do this?

But when I try to call `pdftotext.pl` inside my perl script I am getting a `No such file` error.

**#program to extract text from pdf and save it in a text file**

```
use PDF;

use CAM::PDF;

use CAM::PDF::PageText;

use warnings;

use IPC::System::Simple qw(system capture);

$filein = 'sample.pdf';                                                                   
$fileout = 'output1.txt';  

open OUT, ">$fileout" or die "error: $!";

open IN, "getpdftext.pl $filein" or die "error :$!" ;

while(<IN>)
{
    print OUT $fileout;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It would probably be easier to make getpdftext.pl to do what you want.

Working with the code from getpdftext.pl, this (untested code) should output the pdf to a text file.

```
my $filein = 'sample.pdf';                                                                   
my $fileout = 'output1.txt';  

my $doc = CAM::PDF->new($filein) || die "$CAM::PDF::errstr\n";
open my $fo, '>', $fileout or die "error: $!";

foreach my $p ( 1 .. $doc->numPages() ) {
    my $str = $doc->getPageText($p);
    if (defined $str) {
       CAM::PDF->asciify(\$str);
       print $fo $str;
    }
}

close $fo;
```

Comment: You're welcome.  You can also just work directly with the text instead of printing it to a file if you would prefer. Possibly by changing `open my $fo ...` to `my $docstr = '';` and `print $fo $str;` to `$docstr .= $str;` and working with it instead of `close $fo;`.

Answer (score 0):

See [`perldoc -f open`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#open). You want to take the output stream of an external command and use it as an input stream inside your Perl script. That's what the `-|` mode is for:

```
open my $IN, '-|', "getpdftext.pl $filein" or die $!;
while (<$IN>) {
   ...
}
```